# Opencart 3.0.3.2 - Grabbing Multidimensional Array on Ajax + Twig

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, twig

Good day, Im having some troubles trying to get an array on admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.twig ajax function to display it into a custom `<select>`, this array is given by the `autocomplete()` function on admin/controller/catalog/option.php, the new array values are stored in `'parent_option_value'  => $parent_option_value_data`.
I've been messing around changing things like `$('#option-values' + option_row)` to `$('#parent-option-values' + option_row)` and other elements with no success.

The new *array()* does get the data but Im unable to show its values on the first `<select>`.
What I need to add and change to get this array to be shown as the 2nd Option Values `<select>` does?

**admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.twig**

```
      <!-- The Array I Need -->
      if (parent_option_id > 0) {
          html += '  <td class="text-left"><select name="product_option[' + option_row + '][product_option_value][' + option_value_row + '][option_value_id]" class="form-control">';
          html += $('#option-values' + option_row).html();
          html += '  </select><input type="hidden" name="product_option[' + option_row + '][product_option_value][' + option_value_row + '][product_option_value_id]" value="" /></td>';
      }
      <!--/ The Array I Need /-->

      html += '  <td class="text-left"><select name="product_option[' + option_row + '][product_option_value][' + option_value_row + '][option_value_id]" class="form-control">';
      html += $('#option-values' + option_row).html();
      html += '  </select><input type="hidden" name="product_option[' + option_row + '][product_option_value][' + option_value_row + '][product_option_value_id]" value="" /></td>';
```

**admin/controller/catalog/option.php**

```
public function autocomplete() {
...
                if ($option['parent_id'] > 0) {
                    $json[] = array(
                        'parent_option_id'     => $option['parent_id'],
                        'option_id'            => $option['option_id'],
                        'name'                 => strip_tags(html_entity_decode($option['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')),
                        'category'             => $type,
                        'type'                 => $option['type'],
                        'parent_option_value'  => $parent_option_value_data,
                        'option_value'         => $option_value_data
                    );
                } else {
                    $json[] = array(
                        'parent_option_id'     => $option['parent_id'],
                        'option_id'            => $option['option_id'],
                        'name'                 => strip_tags(html_entity_decode($option['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')),
                        'category'             => $type,
                        'type'                 => $option['type'],
                        'option_value'         => $option_value_data
                    );
                }
            }
...
```